# Execute WordPress Action or Hook from External CRON

Tags: php, wordpress, cron, hook

Is there a way to execute a WordPress action/hook from a server-side CRON job?

I'm not talking about WordPress cron tasks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically you schedule an event (action/hook) using:

```
wp_schedule_event($timestamp, $recurrence, $hook, $args);
```

Then to execute it using a server-side CRON , you would load WordPress's `wp-cron.php`.

This can be problematic because WP has it's own internal (not-real) Cron, so it's best to disable it completely using `define(‘DISABLE_WP_CRON’, true);` to avoid conflicts.

There are lots of articles on this you can read by searching for "*Replacing WordPress cron*" or "Using real cron with WordPress", so you know what you're in for (for example you can also lock the cron).

Comment: I see! It wasn't until your answer that I understood what loading `wp-cron.php` actually did... thanks!